# Circular linked list not working after appending 3rd node

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, circular-dependency

It's Showing output for 2 nodes but after adding 3rd node it  doesn't showing any output,
what i'm doing anything wrong??
This is the append method that i have written all the other program have no errors i have tested all the things.

```
void append(nd element)
{
    nd temp = head;
    nd temp1 = null;
    while(temp != null)
    {
        temp1 = temp;
        temp = temp.nxt;
    }
    element.nxt = head;
    temp1.nxt = element;
}

void printCLL()
{
        nd temp = head;
        
        do
        {
            System.out.print(temp.data+" --> ");
            temp = temp.nxt;
        }
        while(temp != head);
}

public static void  main(String ar[])
{
        CLList clobj = new CLList();

        nd nn1 = new nd(10);
        clobj.head = nn1;    //working
        nd nn2 = new nd(20);   
        clobj.append(nn2);     //working
        nd nn3 = new nd(30); 
        clobj.append(nn3);   //not working
        nd nn4 = new nd(40);
        clobj.append(nn4);    //not working
         
        nd nn5 = new nd(25); 
        clobj.insertAfter(nn1, nn5); //this method also working if node added 
                
        System.out.println("Printing Circular LinkedList : ");
        
        clobj.printCLL();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition `temp1 != null` is not correct, as it assumes the list is *not* cyclic and has an end. But as your list is cyclic, the loop will keep iterating.

So you should not compare with `null` but with `head`:

```
void append(nd element)
{
    if (head == null) {
        head = element;
    } else {
        nd temp = head;
        // Find node that precedes head
        while (temp.nxt != head) 
        {
            temp = temp.nxt;
        }
        temp.nxt = element;
    }
    element.nxt = head;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it's Resolved